# How do you get the package name from a Composer event?

Tags: composer-php

## The Problem

I'm attempting to set up a post-update script with Composer that checks to see which package is being updated. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to consistently get the package name from a `Composer\Installer\PackageEvent`.

## Attempts to solve

The source code says that `$packageEvent->getOperation->getReason()` [*should* return a string](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Operation/OperationInterface.php#L32), but in my testing is actually returning an instance of `Composer\DependencyResolver\GenericRule`.

Calling `Composer\DependencyResolver\Rule::getReasonData()` *sometimes* returns a string (the package name), and *sometimes* returns `Composer\Package\Link`.

The following code mostly works to figure out the package's name:

```
$reasonData = $packageEvent->getOperation()->getReason()->getReasonData();
$packageName = is_string($reasonData) ? $reasonData : $reasonData->getTarget();
```

except *sometimes* `$packageEvent->getOperation()->getReason()` returns null.

## The Question

How do you consistently get the package name from a Composer PackageEvent?

## Bonus Points

How do you get the name of the package being installed/updated/etc. from [all of the Composer event classes](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-classes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mistake! Composer operations still have access to packages, just through different methods, which depend on whether the operation is an `InstallOperation` or an `UpdateOperation`. The following works:

```
/**
 * Returns the package name associated with $event
 *
 * @param PackageEvent $event Package event
 * @return string
 */
public static function getPackageName(PackageEvent $event)
{
    /** @var InstallOperation|UpdateOperation $operation */
    $operation = $event->getOperation();

    $package = method_exists($operation, 'getPackage')
        ? $operation->getPackage()
        : $operation->getInitialPackage();

    return $package->getName();
}
```